# how to use mysql variable inside select statement / how to use 'as' variable in next select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
select 
count(invoice.id) as count_invoice_id, // i want to simply use count_invoice_id instead of using count(discount_offer.id) again inside the if statement below
if(count(invoice.id) > 1 , 'true','false') // i want to used count_invoice_id here
from invoice as invoice
left join discount_offer as discount_offer 
on invoice.id = discount_offer.invoice_id;
```

Above is my sql , is it possible if I want to used count_invoice_id inside of the if statement. Currently what I did is repeat again count method on the invoice.id column.

I want to change from 'count(invoice.id)' to 'count_invoice_id' inside the if statement in the sql above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT count_invoice_id, IF(count_invoice_id > 1 , 'true', 'false')
FROM   (SELECT    COUNT(invoice.id) AS count_invoice_id
        FROM      invoice
        LEFT JOIN discount_offer ON invoice.id = discount_offer.invoice_id) t
```

Comment: Thanks , that's working , but is there's any other ways to achieve this?